# Treat page URL as image URL

Tags: php, image, url

I want to use page url eg. `example.com/randomimage/` in HTML `<img>` tag to display random images.

Is that possible with PHP?

I can change `/randomimage/` page code via `page-randomimage.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return an HTML page from your PHP script for that to work.  In HTML, `<img>` tags are designed to load image content, not HTML content.

Instead you could program `page-randomimpage.php` to **redirect** to a random image URL.  Something like [this random redirect script](https://gist.github.com/racinmat/874de00981056dca8ed0) but with image URLs in it rather than website URLs.   The redirects should be "302 Temporary" type redirects so that the redirector result is not cached by browsers.